# How to tell Visual Studio or to pickup a file and deploy it to the bin directory after build?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I do have few config files and dll files that are needed in order to run the final product and I want to instruct visual studio build to pick them up.

So far it was easy to add them to the project but I wasn't able to identify the correct mix of properties that I need to setup for these files, in order to get the files inside the bin directory (target).

Note: the term deploy here doed not refer to the after build deployment, that would be a custom task anyway.

So far I see these options:

- Excluded from Build: No
- Content: Yes
- Item Type: contains a list of ~20 options but none of them sounds like something that would work. I already tried most of them.

Answer (score 1):

Select the project that requires the configuration file and right click on it and then select **Properties**.
Go  to the **Build Events** tab and type in the **Post-Build event command line** something like the following

```
copy pathfiletocopy $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)
```

now you could check the **Copy Only on Successful Build** option.

Of course you need to adapt the command line to your liking.
You can also press the button Edit Post-build and see a list of predefined macros that refers to specific informations related to your projects and solution. You could also insert other CMD shell commands like **IF $(ConfigurationName) == "Release"** to execute commands only when you compile for release instead of debug (for example running an obfuscator)

Comment: Thanks Steve, that's mostly the current implementation but I do NOT want to use the copy mecanism for two reasons: one it does always copy (still I could use robocopy and include it in my project because it does not come with windows). Also, the second reason is that it is hard to update the  list of files to be copied. I do still think it should be a way to see the filed in the solution explorer and be able to add/remove them from there. If there is no alternative I will consider this the answer :)

Comment: I have added a project folder called ExternalLibs to my projects and in this folder I have added a batch command that is called in the post-build event. The batch file contains the copy commands required. The single files are added directly in this ExternalLibs folder. So I can easily see all the files involved and simply opening the batch file I can REM to Include/Exclude the files to copy. Also remember the property `Copy To Output Directory` that could help you with each single file. Hope it helps